# Deep link ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME

Tags: android, deep-linking

That is my activity declaration

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:host="example"
                android:path="/"
                android:scheme="ray1984" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

In genymotion emulator I open my simple html

```
<html>
<body>
    <a href="intent://example/#Intent;scheme=ray1984;package=com.github.ray1984.deeplink;end">Deep link</a>
</body>
```

On link click I expect application opening, but I'm getting error net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME

Also I tried simple deep link - `<a href="ray1984://example">` - but I'm getting the same error.

**UPDATE**
I've changed html by advices:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
var custom = "ray1984://example";
var alt = "http://google.com/";
var g_intent = "intent://example/#Intent;scheme=ray1984;package=com.github.ray1984.deplink;end";
var timer;
var heartbeat;
var iframe_timer;

function clearTimers() {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    clearTimeout(heartbeat);
    clearTimeout(iframe_timer);
}

function intervalHeartbeat() {
    if (document.webkitHidden || document.hidden) {
        clearTimers();
    }
}

function tryIframeApproach() {
    var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
    iframe.style.border = "none";
    iframe.style.width = "1px";
    iframe.style.height = "1px";
    iframe.onload = function () {
        document.location = alt;
    };
    iframe.src = custom;
    document.body.appendChild(iframe);
}

function tryWebkitApproach() {
    document.location = custom;
    timer = setTimeout(function () {
        document.location = alt;
    }, 2500);
}

function useIntent() {
    document.location = g_intent;
}

function launch_app_or_alt_url(el) {
    heartbeat = setInterval(intervalHeartbeat, 200);
    if (navigator.userAgent.match(/Chrome/)) {
        useIntent();
    } else if (navigator.userAgent.match(/Firefox/)) {
        tryWebkitApproach();
        iframe_timer = setTimeout(function () {
            tryIframeApproach();
        }, 1500);
    } else {
        tryIframeApproach();
    }
}

$(".source_url").click(function (event) {
    launch_app_or_alt_url($(this));
    event.preventDefault();
});
</script>
   </head>
     <body>
       <button class="source_url">Click me</button>
     </body>
</html>
```

But on button click nothing happens

Answer (score 0):

```
Do these changes

change function launch_app_or_alt_url(el) to function launch_app_or_alt_url()

and remove this 
$(".source_url").click(function (event) {
    launch_app_or_alt_url($(this));
    event.preventDefault();
});

and change this <button class="source_url">Click me</button> to
<input type="button" value="click" onClick="launch_app_or_alt_url()" />
```